# Enable favicon on Apache 2 with SSL

Tags: apache2

After moving from HTTP to SSL in Apache configs I cannot anymore access the favicon on the server.

The part of responsible config looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/project/project/

        Alias /favicon.ico /home/ubuntu/project/static/favicon.ico
        Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/project/static/

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Folder exists and favicon is located in it.

When I am trying to access favicon.ico I get 403:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /favicon.ico on this
>   server.

How can I solve it?

Here is the output of:

`namei -lx /home/ubuntu/project/static/favicon.icof:`

```
/home/ubuntu/project/static/favicon.ico
Drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
drwxr-xr-x ubuntu ubuntu ubuntu
drwxrwxr-x ubuntu ubuntu project
drwxrwxr-x ubuntu ubuntu static
-rw-rw-r-- ubuntu ubuntu favicon.ico
```

Comment: Include the output of `namei -lx /home/ubuntu/project/static/favicon.ico` please.

Comment: @muru As I wrote file exists in the folder. The output -rw-rw-r-- ubuntu ubuntu favicon.ico

Comment: @muru I have provided the full trace. Probably it will be helpful

Comment: So that rules out in one shot most permission issues. Now it's apache's turn. I'm curious about what happens if you access `/static` - any errors there?

Comment: @muru if to request /static/ then I get the same 403 error. I think the error is related to SSL cause with HTTP favicon was working as I remember

Comment: could be. While you have set the vhost to be on port 443, there's absolutely no SSL configuration for it, no certificates or anything

Comment: @muru as I wrote in question it is only a part of config. All the rest is not related.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
chmod +r favicon.ico
```

in your var/www/html folder

Comment: Can you explain the mechanism? The execute bit seems somewhat unrelated to reading the file.

Comment: You are right its only +r, my bad!

Answer (score -1):

Your favicon.ico file has not sufficient permission.

I would set favicon.ico file with :

> chmod 505 favicon.ico

Then save again favicon.ico with now new permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is not working. I tried it but still wondering if I should give x rights for favicon to be displayed!